# Why fabric "The Fabric iOS and Android mobile apps will be sunset on November 30, 2018. After this date, you will not be able to log into the apps"?

Tags: google-fabric

Why fabric "The Fabric iOS and Android mobile apps will be sunset on November 30, 2018. After this date, you will not be able to log into the apps" is it closing?

Comment: If you go to their site you will see this message: We are integrating the best of Fabric into Firebase to give you one powerful platform. Check out our roadmap for more information on what to do and what to expect. And there is a Learn more button.

Answer (score 19):

Just check this official post. 
https://get.fabric.io/roadmap

Fabric Beta will be moved into Firebase on Early 2019.

> *Start using the next generation of Crashlytics Beta Get valuable feedback on pre-release iOS and Android apps by using Firebase App
>   Distribution, the new version of Crashlytics Beta, to distribute beta
>   builds to your team.*

Comment: Does anybody else find it worrying that they will stop allowing us to distribute apps through Fabric at the end of November 2018 while not allowing us to distribute using their replacement service until "Early 2019"?

Comment: Edit: Ah they mean the "Fabric app" not the "Beta app". As you were....

Comment: will it remain free?

Answer (score 12):

Fabric was bought by Google and is being integrated into Firebase ("the best of Fabric" is being integrated).

Google will support Fabric until mid 2019. See [Roadmap](https://get.fabric.io/roadmap).

The warning message means Fabric mobile apps will not work anymore after November 30, 2018. However, you can still use the web app at [fabric.io](https://fabric.io/) until mid 2019.

Comment: What mobile apps? Their or ours?

Comment: @FlorescuCătălin They mean Fabric mobile app in App Store and Play Store. Not your own. After mid 2019, however, you need to continue using your dashboard via Firebase

Comment: @OnurD. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From their FAQ:

> What is the plan for Fabric’s mobile app?
>
> Fabric’s iOS and Android apps will be available until November 30th, 2018. After this point, you’ll still be able to monitor your migrated apps on the go **using the Firebase Console, which is designed to work well on mobile devices**.

Comment: Yea... on iPhone half of page is trimmed and you can't scroll it horizontally :<

Answer (score -1):

Deprecated by Google, fabric is being killed because it was better than Google's firebase.

I can't stand how Google insists you use specific services then deprecates them...